# JavaScript code for showing and hiding multiple menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JavaScript I don't understand it that well.

I used this code: but I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Untitled 1</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
      var $bgs = $('.menu-toggle');
      $('.menu-item').click(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).data('target')).stop(true).slideToggle();
        $bgs.not($target).filter(':visible').stop(true, true).slideUp();
      })
    })
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="menu-item menu-item-1" data-target=".recovery-bg">
    <a href="#">Recovery</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item menu-item-2" data-target=".forensic-bg">
    <a href="#">Forensics</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item menu-item-3" data-target=".erasure-bg">
    <a href="#">Erasure</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item menu-item-4" data-target=".training-bg">
    <a href="#">Training</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item menu-item-5" data-target=".product-bg">
    <a href="#">Products</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-toggle recovery-bg">
    recovery-bg
  </div>
  <div class="menu-toggle forensic-bg">
    forensic-bg
  </div>
  <div class="menu-toggle erasure-bg">
    erasure-bg
  </div>
  <div class="menu-toggle training-bg">
    training-bg
  </div>
  <div class="menu-toggle product-bg">
    product-bg
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I did get this same code from this website, but I've had no luck whatsoever.

Comment: If you run the snippet you'll see an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined `. Your code appears to work fine when you include jQuery in the page: https://jsfiddle.net/dtx3L6cr/

Comment: As Rory says, just add a reference to jquery to the snippet and it works fine. What exactly is happening currently that you think should/shouldn't be?

Comment: Did you add jQuery to your scripts? Add this inside your `<head></head>` tag:  `<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks Guys this is quite interesting. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw in your code that you are using jquery function but you didn't even call it to your html page.

**Step1:**
Download your [jquery](https://jquery.com/)

**Step2:**
call it to your html page

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because missing referance. You must add a reference.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```